# How to resolve "Do you want to allow" <site.x> to use up to 1.4 GB of storage on your Mac?

Tags: safari, storage

I am using Safari on a Mac and I imagine that the problem is a combination of the two.  The exact website I see it for is https://weaintgotnohistory.sbnation.com, but I understand this can happen with a number of different websites.

I see the matter talked about at https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/do-you-want-to-allow-yahoo-to-use-up-to-1-2-gb-of-storage-on-your-mac.2227032/, however following the steps within Safari, the url does not show up at all, so there is nothing I can configure.

If I push don't allow, next time I load a page from that site I get the same dialog.
If I push allow, I will get a dialog with a higher number (higher than 1.4 GB) next time

How do I resolve this?  In particular:

1. How would I remove this content, whatever it is.  There is now way that that site should need 1.4 GB.
2. How would I set a limit for a site so that it does not ask me if I want to allow storage?

Comment: You can take a slightly inconvenient step and "remove all" data. At worst you'll be logged out. No history deletion, no password losses. Also Develop Menu > empty cache is slightly less inconvenient. https://pastebin.com/8R2855Q1 here's all the websites connected to. In case you want to do case by case deletion.

Comment: I used `Develop > Empty Caches` and `Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data` to delete site-relevant cookies.